# Return a list containing 2-tuples (x,y) x and y are numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to import data from excel to a specific format but I have not been successful

This is what I need to get (list with 2-tuples (x,y) x and y are numpy.ndarray):

```
data=[(array([[1.0],[10.0]]),array([100.0])), (array([[2.0],[20.0]]),array([200.0])), (array([[3.0],[30.0]]),array([300.0])),(array([[4.0],[40.0]]),array([400.0]))]
```

This is my best result:

```
data=[[array([[ 1.],
         [10.]]) 100.0]
 [array([[ 2.],
       [20.]]) 200.0]
 [array([[ 3.],
       [30.]]) 300.0]
 [array([[ 4.],
       [40.]]) 400.0]]
```

This is my code:

```
data1=np.array([1,2,3,4])
data2=np.array([10,20,30,40])
Yarray=np.array([100,200,300,400])

Merge1_2=np.array(zip(data1, data2))
Xarray=Merge1_2.reshape((Merge1_2.shape[0],Merge1_2.shape[1],1))

Data=np.array(zip(Xarray, Yarray))
```

Thank you

Comment: your "best result" is a syntax error.

Comment: You need to replace `data1=np.array[1,2,3,4]` by `data1=np.array([1,2,3,4])` for others to be able to work in the first step with your data. I prefer you edit it yourself. Same applies to the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, stack the X arrays (put one "on top" of the other). Add a new dimension to convert `[1,10]` tp `[[1],[10]]`. Transpose the result to swap rows and columns. Finally, zip the 3D array and the Y array:

```
list(zip(np.stack([data1, data2])[np.newaxis,:,:].T, 
                           Yarray[np.newaxis,:].T))
#[(array([[ 1], [10]]), array([100])), 
# (array([[ 2], [20]]), array([200])), 
# (array([[ 3], [30]]), array([300])), 
# (array([[ 4], [40]]), array([400]))]
```

Comment: He needs `1` and `10` as `[1]` and `[10]` and so on. I didn't down vote though.

Comment: @Bazingaa Sure. Fixed.